# Quantifier in Java {n} is taking n+1 input

Tags: java, regex, quantifiers

```
public static boolean validateState (String state)
{
return state.matches( "[1-9]\\d{2}-[1-9]\\d{4}" ) ;
}
```

Why this function takes 3 digit before hyphen and 5 after hyphen when i have put 2 and 4 in the brackets? Kindly Help..

Comment: Easy, because you put `[1-9]` before it, you probably want `\\d{2}-\\d{4}`, but note that `\d` is `[0-9]` and not `[1-9]`

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `[1-9]` in both cases. You're actually trying to match:

- a digit (1-9), followed by
- two digits, followed by
- a hyphen, followed by
- a digit (1-9), followed by
- four digits

Or to put it more succinctly: `[0-9]` is equivalent to `\\d`.

You probably either need `[1-9]\\d-[1-9]\\d{3}` or just `\\d{2}-\\d{4}`.

Answer (score 1):

For the RegEx which you have provided "[1-9]\d{2}-[1-9]\d{4}"

a) [1-9] accepts one digit

b)  d{2} accepts two digits

So, totally it accepts 3 digits(before the hyphen, i.e, for "[1-9]\d{2}" part).

Likewise, after hyphen also it will accept 4 digits.

You probably want to use any one of the following:

1) \d{2}-\d{4}

2) [1-9]\d{1}-[1-9]\d{3}